# Android: "Navigation Type: Fixed Tabs + Swipe"

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I'm trying to use Tabs + Swipe in an App and want to use the Navigation Type "Fixed Tabs + Swipe" which the ADT provides me when creating an Activity.

Sooo now the ADT spits out nice Code, which I slightly modified...

I completely understand the code and what's going on... But how can I teach the App to use my three Fragments instead of the stupid Dummy Frag? :(

I cannot find any tutorial which deals with the ADTs "Navigation Types"...

Thanks for your help!

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });
    //Adding Tabs
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}

public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I came across a slightly modified solution that solves the ObjectFragment segment of the code. It works well for me. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380391/tabs-and-swipe-editing-the-getitem-to-display-3-different-fragments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how can I teach the App to use my three Fragments instead of the stupid Dummy Frag?

You will notice that `DummySectionFragment` is referenced in `getItem()` of the `SectionsPagerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
    // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

If you want to use different fragments, modify `getItem()` to return the fragment you want, given the supplied `position` (0-based page number).

Comment: Thanks, now i changed my getItem() to a switch-case depending on "position" and added three classes (one for each Fragment) at the end of my MainActivity.java... Is there any way to solve my problem nicer or better? :)

Comment: @Jonas: Since I do not know what you consider to be "nicer or better", I cannot really answer that. I usually have my fragments as separate public Java classes, as they can get a bit lengthy. Otherwise, what you have sounds reasonable.

Comment: Okay then :) 
Muchas gracias @CommonsWare !

Comment: Jonas - I've been facing the same problem and I wondered if you could share your "getItem() to a switch-case" and may be your complete "public Fragment getItem(int position)" example / edits. I'm just learning Java and like you I understand the concept of fragments but getting the hang of the example has not been easy. I'm assuming its along the logic lines of is arg = 1 then call fragment xxx ? I've already setup new fragments as @CommonsWare suggested. Thanks in advance. T

Answer (score 5):

a switch-case to set the fragments is easy and makes it really clear. Let each of your fragment inflate the root view in your xml

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(index){
    case 0:
         fragment = new Fragment1();
         break;
    case 1:
         fragment = new Fragment2();
         break;
    case 2:
         fragment = new Fragment3();
         break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    //set args if necessary (which it isn't?)
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ObjectFragment.ARG_OBJECT, index + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    //return fragment
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by ObjectFragment?