# Tabs and Swipe - editing the getItem to display 3 different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been at this for about 3 days looking up various websites for reference, but I am stuck. I am using the swipe and tabs layout which give you the standard dummy section fragment. But I have 3 separate fragments that I want to display different .xml layouts for. This is the section of code that is bothering me:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
            Fragment fragment3 = new DummySectionFragment3();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment2.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment3.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 3);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            fragment2.setArguments(args);
            fragment3.setArguments(args);
            return fragment2;

        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment2 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment2() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, container, false);

            return rootView2;
        }
    }

    public static class DummySectionFragment3 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number_3";

        public DummySectionFragment3() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_3, container, false);

            return rootView3;
        }
    }

}
```

This returns fragment 2. I want to display 3 fragments when each tab is selected. How do I do it? I'm guessing that it's what is returning right?

edit.. ive included the whole java class.. in the hope i can resove this.. [How do I use FragmentPagerAdapter to have tabs with different content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149778/how-do-i-use-fragmentpageradapter-to-have-tabs-with-different-content?rq=1) ive just tried the following (Second Answer as i didnt understnd what was meant in the first)  it didnt work

Comment: no 1? i my of asked the wrong question but i aint sure how to ask what im looking for.. i basically want 3 tbs to display 3 different views tht have different content, as it is now its showing the fragment 2 on all pages..

Comment: because you always return fragment 2 in get Item method.

Comment: yea i guessed that part, how do i set it to return each fragment depending on which tb im viewing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the method this way:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(fragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;

          case 1:
            Fragment fragment2 = new DummySectionFragment2();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(fragment2 .ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 2);
            fragment2.setArguments(args);
            return fragment2;

          case 2:

             Fragment fragment3 = new DummySectionFragment3();
             Bundle args = new Bundle();
             args.putInt(fragment3.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 3);
             fragment3.setArguments(args);
             return fragment3;


        default:
            return null;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thats the default way it set out, but shows the dummy fragment on all tabs

Comment: use Switch/Case or if/else statement for the position. See my edit.

Comment: For the love of God use factory for that, not the switch/case =)