# Swipe View and Multiple Fragments Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipe

I'm trying to make an application that has two fragments that are both different in function and you can swipe right to go between them. I've looked into how to do this, but no solution seems to work.
[Tabs and Swipe - editing the getItem to display 3 different fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380391/tabs-and-swipe-editing-the-getitem-to-display-3-different-fragments)
Im trying to implement a getitem similar to this, but as you can see in this code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by cwallace on 11/10/14.
 */
//Implement PagerAdapter Class to handle individual page creation
class MyPagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment =  new InitialFragment();
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I want to return a different type of fragment than the function wants, and I can't cast my Initial Fragment to the Fragment class. Am I even attempting to do this the correct way?

Comment: So you have two different fragments you want to use? InitialFragment & some other one? The code you posted looks fine, you would just have to put an if/else inside the getItem method so it knows where to put each of the fragments. postion 0 and then position 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's point out some things.

1. `can't cast my Initial Fragment`, make sure that your initialFragment class **extends the Fragment.**
2. As @hitch.united suggest, **in getItem() of adapter** , you can return the fragment by the id in a if-else. But remember that: **You should not use this function to retrieve the fragment!**
3. I can suggest you by using the **ViewPager** for swipe operation.

Comment: Yes, I was extending the default Android fragment class instead of the  Android support v4 Fragment. Thanks!

Comment: It is glad to help you.
Keep coding bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
class MyPagesAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyPagesAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new InitialFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new YourSecondFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting an incompatible types error when assigning fragment to a new InitialFragment

Comment: Then your `InitialFragment` is **not extending** the `Fragment`

Comment: Yep, I was extending the default android fragment rather than the support.v4 fragment!

Comment: But in the `getItem` your `Fragment` is exactly `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`, so you need to extends your `InitialFragment` from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`